# Big-O Efficiency measurement

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, big-o

I'm a java student who wants to get a better understanding of the big-O efficiency.

For this problem, it is assumed that `doIt()` has an efficiency of `O(n)`.

```
 j=n;

 while (j>0) {

    doIt();

    j = j / 2;

}

i = 1;

while (i < n) {

i = i * 2;

doIt();

}
```

What would be the big o efficiency of this algorithm, and why would it be that efficiency (such as `O(n logn)`, `O(n^2)`, `O(n^2 logn)`, etc.).

Answer (score 1):

First loop is `O(nlog(n))` and the second on is the same. Hence the total complexity is `O(nlog(n))`.

Also, instead of big-O can big-`\Theta` notation too.

For the first loop, number of iterations is the number of dividing `n` by `2` which is `log(n)` and the second loop can be explained the same (by multiplication instead of division).

Comment: i see, thanks for the clarification. That makes much more sense now.

Answer (score 1):

Due to the halving, the first loop will execute `log(n)` times. The second loop will also execute `log(n)` times due to the doubling.

This means that `doIt()` will be called `log(n)` times per loop, yielding a total execution time of `O(nlog(n)+nlog(n))`, or `O(2nlog(n))`. As standard, drop the constant to yield your complexity of `O(nlog(n))`